# How do I optimise this code to one loop or minimal possible

Tags: python, optimization

I need to restrict this code to maximum one loop or fewer if possible:

```
for i in range(1,count+1):

  for j in range(i+1,count+1):

     newcount+=1
```

Basically what it does is find possible combinations without repition .

Comment: `newcount += (count-1)*count/2`

Comment: Can you not use `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser: If `i,j` aren't used at all, that would be an overkill.

Comment: @EricDuminil yes. Agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) between `1` and `count - 1`:

```
count * (count - 1) // 2
```

Here's a small test:

```
count = 10
newcount = 0

for i in range(1,count+1):
  for j in range(i+1,count+1):
     newcount+=1

print(newcount)
# 45
print(newcount == count * (count - 1) // 2)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

In your case, you can iterator over `itertools.combinations(xrange(1, count+1), 2)`

Comment: @EricDuminil right, I went too fast here. I'll edit as not to lead people on the wrong direction.